# Configure SSL for openvpn on synology diskstation

Tags: openvpn, synology, stunnel

I currently have a Synology DS218J and I have openvpn installed on it. I'm wondering how to configure SSL tunneling between the VPN server and the client. I did hear something about stunnel but I'm not 100% sure if it is even supported by my diskstation.  If needed I can provide the config files for my openVPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run OpenVPN in TLS mode. You can read about it here: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/security-overview.html

Comment: If I may ask, would that prevent my connection from being blocked by the great firewall?

Comment: I'm sorry but you need to be more specific. Describe what your network looks like and what you are trying to accomplish (what problem do you solve)? Thank you.

Comment: Okay so I have the Synology diskstation in Canada that is running OpenVPN. I am leaving for china for vacation and I'd like to be able to connect to sites blocked in China so I'm planning on connecting to the diskstation from China. I did hear that openVPN is blocked but I heard that having the connection be 'wrapped' in a layer of SSL will help avoid the great firewall of china block.

Comment: It's quite easy to detect it when a firewall is inspecting deep and by force. I would turn to DNS instead. It's not as widely used (or known, really) but if you have an own domain hosted on your dns server you would be able to tunnel your traffic by resolving A:tunneled-pdu.yourdomain.com. There are tools out there that work in the wild.

Comment: I see, I'll take a look into those options. Thanks for your help.